# How to attach Arduino MKR1000 to a shield meant for Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, hardware, adafruit, mkr1000

I have an Arduino MKR1000 and need to interface it to an Adafruit Music Maker shield, which has pinouts for an Arduino UNO.

Maybe I'll have to attach female headers, and then jumper pins over.
Which pins on MKR go to which pins on Music Maker?

I have to use the MKR1000 because I'm getting the audio from wifi (using MKR1000) and then sending it to Music Maker.

Comment: This sort-of sounds like your 1st Arduino project.  The jump from using a Atmel ATmega328P processor to an Atmel ARM processor, in my experience, is not free from problems. Let alone the differences in the boards.  I would suggest you prototype your project using the intended host, the Arduino Uno.  Then try using the MKR1000.  You obviously can't do everything with the Uno.  But I would at least talk to the Music Maker using a Uno then try it with the MKR1000.  Add more features and repeat the test until you have exhausted what you can do on the Uno platform.

Comment: The intended host is MKR1000, not UNO.

Comment: Yes yes, I'm suggesting, if you are having problems with the MKR1000, to try small parts of your code on the Uno - the intended host of the Adafruit Music Maker PCB.  If the code, Uno and Music Maker board work and switching to the MKR1000 does not, then you know you either have a wiring problem or switching from the ATmega328P processor to the ARM processor is causing unexpected difficulties.  As to which pins go where, if the MKR1000 is touted as 100% Arduino compatible, then the pin labeling should match.  Be sure to check if both boards are designed for the same voltage (5v or 3.3V)!

Comment: Wowa, did you read this?: "Warning: Unlike most Arduino & Genuino boards, the MKR1000 runs at 3.3V. The maximum voltage that the I/O pins can tolerate is 3.3V. "   Double check how the Adafruit Music Maker board is put together!  There's some talk on the Adafruit Music Maker product page about level shifting but it sounded a bit vague.  Since both these items are on the Adafruit web site you might post a Music Maker / MKR1000 compatibility question directly to them on one of their forums.